# Custom Button not showing Images for all Instances - Kivy

Tags: python, kivy

I have created a class mybutton which inherits from Button & Image. Here are my `.py` and `.kv` codes.

**main.py**

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.garden.navigationdrawer import NavigationDrawer as ND
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.image import Image

class navwindow(ND):
    def __init__(self,**kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)

class mybutton(Button,Image):
    pass
class mainapp(App):
    def build(self):
        return navwindow()
    #theme_cls = ThemeManager() #very important

if __name__=='__main__':
    mainapp().run()
```

**main.kv**

```
<mybutton@Button>:
    size_hint: 1, None
    GridLayout:
        rows:1
        Image:
            source:'icons/ask.png'
        Label:
            text:''
<navwindow>:
    anim_type:'slide_above_simple'
    id:mainwin
    BoxLayout:
        orientation:'vertical'
        spacing: 10
        canvas.before:
            Color:
                rgba:(1,1,1,1)
            Rectangle:
                pos:self.pos
                size:self.size
        ScrollView:
            GridLayout:
                size_hint_y:None
                height: self.minimum_height
                cols:1
                Image:
                    source:'icons/try.png'
                    size_hint_y:None
                Label:
                    text:'Chitkaran@gmail.com'
                    color:(0,0,0,1)
                    size_hint_y:None
                mybutton:
                    text:'heaadadadllo'
                mybutton:
                    text:'hello'
                mybutton:
                    text:'hello'
```

**Problem:** *When I run the code, Only the last button shows the icon image.*

I have attached the screenshot of the output to explain the problem properly.

Please Assist.
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On way to accomplish this is to just subclass the `Button` class and redefine how it is drawn. I have added an `icon` property to the `mybutton` class. The code in the `kv` string for `mybutton` is just the default for the `Button` (from `style.kv`) with some small changes to handle the `icon` property:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.garden.navigationdrawer import NavigationDrawer as ND
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty
from kivy.uix.button import Button


class navwindow(ND):
    def __init__(self,**kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)


class mybutton(Button):
    icon = ObjectProperty(None)


Builder.load_string('''
<mybutton>:
    state_image: self.background_normal if self.state == 'normal' else self.background_down
    disabled_image: self.background_disabled_normal if self.state == 'normal' else self.background_disabled_down
    canvas:
        Color:
            rgba: self.background_color
        BorderImage:
            border: self.border
            pos: self.pos
            size: self.size
            source: self.disabled_image if self.disabled else self.state_image
        Color:
            rgba: 1, 1, 1, 1
        Rectangle:
            texture: self.texture
            size:  self.texture_size
            pos: int(0.75 * self.right - self.texture_size[0] / 2.0), int(self.center_y - self.texture_size[1] / 2.)
        Rectangle:
            source: self.icon
            size: 0.25 * self.width, self.height
            pos: self.pos
<navwindow>:
    anim_type:'slide_above_simple'
    id:mainwin
    BoxLayout:
        orientation:'vertical'
        spacing: 10
        canvas.before:
            Color:
                rgba:(1,1,1,1)
            Rectangle:
                pos:self.pos
                size:self.size
        ScrollView:
            GridLayout:
                size_hint_y:None
                height: self.minimum_height
                cols:1
                Image:
                    source:'icons/try.png'
                    size_hint_y:None
                Label:
                    text:'Chitkaran@gmail.com'
                    color:(0,0,0,1)
                    size_hint_y:None
                mybutton:
                    icon: 'icons/ask.png'
                    text:'heaadadadllo'
                    size_hint: 1, None
                mybutton:
                    icon: 'icons/ask.png'
                    text:'hello'
                    size_hint: 1, None
                mybutton:
                    icon: 'icons/ask.png'
                    text:'hello'
                    size_hint: 1, None
''')


class mainapp(App):
    def build(self):
        return navwindow()
    #theme_cls = ThemeManager() #very important


if __name__=='__main__':
    mainapp().run()
```

The above code will force the icon image to fit in a `Rectangle` that is 1/4 of the width of the `mybutton`, but the full height of the `mybutton`, which may stretch the icon image. If the icon is square, you can avoid stretching by using the following code for the icon `Rectangle`:

```
    Rectangle:
        source: self.icon
        size: 0.25 * self.width, 0.25 * self.width
        pos: self.x, self.y + 0.5 * (self.height - 0.25 * self.width)
```

This should work for any square icon. If the icon is not square, you can adjust the above code to account for that. Regardless, doing it this way will only work for icons of the same shape. If you want to handle arbitrary shapes, I suspect it might be possible with some additional code in the `mybutton` class.

Comment: Thanks for the workaround John. However, this doesn't quite answer my query. I want to know what is wrong in my code due to which it doesn't display the icon in the previous buttons.  Please assist

Comment: I don't know the precise answer to your question, but I have seen problems when doing multiple inheritance from Kivy widgets. I suspect the problem has to do with both the `Button` and `Image` classes having `texture` properties, and the default `style.kv` uses `texture` to define how each of those widgets are drawn. So it is unclear how a widget that inherits from both would be drawn.

Comment: Ok, I understand that now.
But, the resolution which you provided stretches the image. I want to use the original dimensions of the icon image. How do I do that ?

Comment: See modified answer above.

Comment: Perfect! Thanks a ton John